# XmlSerializer throwing exception for type, After I used XMLInclude?

Tags: c#, xml, exception, serialization

I'm getting an exception

```
The type KML.Placemark was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
```

When I try to serialize my objects.   I know of two different solutions to this exception, but neither is working in this case.

**Some background:**

I have a Class-structure that closely follows the GoogleEarth/OpenGIS [KML format](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html) (for drawing on top of GoogleEarth).

My root type is `KMLDocument` which contains a set of `KMLObjects`:

```
public class KMLDocument
{
    public KMLObject[] members;
}
```

And `KMLObject` is the base-type for `Feature`, which is the base-type for `Placemark`

---

**The Problem:**

When I construct the serializer for KMLDocument, it won't directly know about derived types like `Placemark` unless I explicitly tell it.  So I do it this way:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KMLDocument),
    new Type[] { typeof(KMLObject),
                 typeof(Feature),
                 typeof(Placemark) } );
```

I also attach Attributes to the `KMLDocument` class to make sure it knows about all important types:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("kml", Namespace="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(KMLObject))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Feature))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Placemark))]
public class KMLDocument
{  ....   }
```

But, despite telling the serializer about `Placemark` two different ways, when I call
serialize, I get the exception:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    KMLDocument kml = new KMLDocument();
    kml.AddPlacemark("MyPlacemark", "MyTest");

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KMLDocument),
        new Type[] { typeof(KMLObject),
                     typeof(Feature), 
                     typeof(Placemark) } );
     serializer.Serialize(new StreamWriter("MyKML.kml"), kml);  // Exception on this line!
}
```

If I add a dummy-variable of type Placemark, suddenly the serializer can find the type, and it works right:

```
public class KMLDocument
{
    public KMLObject[] members;
    public Placemark dummy_var;  // Should NOT be needed!
}
```

What am I missing?  Why are *both* my XmlSerializer-Constructor and my Attributes failing to provide the important information?

Comment: I don't see why it's not working. Have you tried debugging the XmlSerializer generated assembly? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HOWTODebugIntoANETXmlSerializerGeneratedAssembly.aspx

Comment: @Martijn:  I've been looking for the generated assembly, but have been unable to find it so far.

Comment: As noted in the url you don't need the assembly, the pdb en source will do fine. Another more complicated way would be to dump the process to a memory dump file and load that with windbg. Then you can save the dynamicly loaded assembly to disc and examine that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placemark and Feature are subclasses of KMLObject. The `members` field holds a mixed array of Placemarks and Features.

The `members` field has to be tagged with an XmlArrayItemAttribute in order to specify that the elements it contains are polymorphic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx

Comment: Yup, turns out it is the [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Placemark))] that is needed.   The exception message didn't hint that way at all, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am reading this correctly `KMLObject` is a base object from which `Feature` and `Placemark` inherit. And `AddPlacemark()` creates a `Placemark` instance and adds it to the `members` array.

This should help then

```
public class KMLDocument
{
    [XmlElement("Placemark", Type=typeof(Placemark)),
    XmlElement("Feature", Type=typeof(Feature))]
    public KMLObject[] members;
}
```

You shouldn't need any of those inclides that you added to the serializer or the document. I would also declare `members` as `List<KMLObject>` instead of an array.

Comment: members was originally declared as a List<>, but as I reduced the problem more and more, I decided to remove the issue of Generics and substituted in a simple array.   Once I have the problem solved, I'll move back to a List<>.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, thats strange. This complete example seems to work fine (using VS2008 and .NET 3.5).

```
public class KMLDocument
{
   public List<KMLObject> members = new List<KMLObject>();

   public void AddPlacemark(string p, string v)
   {
      members.Add(new Placemark(p, v));
   }

   public void AddFeature()
   {
      members.Add(new Feature());
   }
}

public class KMLObject { }
public class Feature : KMLObject { }
public class Placemark : Feature
{
   public string p;
   public string v;
   public Placemark() { }
   public Placemark(string p1, string v1) { p = p1; v = v1; }
}
```

Then I run it with the following:

```
KMLDocument kml = new KMLDocument();
kml.AddFeature();
kml.AddPlacemark("MyPlacemark", "MyTest");

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KMLDocument),
   new Type[] { typeof(KMLObject),
                typeof(Feature),
                typeof(Placemark) });
serializer.Serialize(new StreamWriter("MyKML.kml"), kml);
```

Then it generates the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<KMLDocument ...>
  <members>
    <KMLObject xsi:type="Feature" />
    <KMLObject xsi:type="Placemark">
      <p>MyPlacemark</p>
      <v>MyTest</v>
    </KMLObject>
  </members>
</KMLDocument>
```

**Update**
You can use [XmlAttributeOverrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to force the XML to create Feature or Placemark values instead of KMLObject's.  Heres what the serialization would look like using my above code.

```
XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();

XmlElementAttribute attr = new XmlElementAttribute();
attr.ElementName = "Feature";
attr.Type = typeof(Feature);
attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);

XmlElementAttribute attr2 = new XmlElementAttribute();
attr2.ElementName = "Placemark";
attr2.Type = typeof(Placemark);
attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr2);

XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
attrOverrides.Add(typeof(KMLDocument), "members", attrs);

KMLDocument kml = new KMLDocument();
kml.AddFeature();
kml.AddPlacemark("MyPlacemark", "MyTest");

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KMLDocument),
   attrOverrides);
serializer.Serialize(new StreamWriter("MyKML2.kml"), kml);
```

This would generate an XML output of the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<KMLDocument ...>
  <Feature />
  <Placemark>
    <p>MyPlacemark</p>
    <v>MyTest</v>
  </Placemark>
</KMLDocument>
```

Comment: Very interesting.  I'll investigate with my setup (VS2010, .NET4.0).  However, in the XML, it left the inner-objects as KMLObject, instead of Feature and Placemark.  Its a requirement for a good KML file that the objects have the right type.

Comment: @abelenky - Ok I see now.  You can use XmlAttributeOverrides to accomplish this (see updated).  Its probably easier to just use the XmlArrayItemAttribute tag, but I've give you a different option incase you want it a bit more dynamic.